# 2 different datasources

Tags: objective-c, ios, datasource, uipickerview

Im making an app and I want to fill two `UITextView` with two different `UIPickerView`.

## My code

---

### controller.h

```
UIPickerView *inputType;
UIPickerView *inputFormat;
```

---

### controller.m

```
inputFormat=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
inputType=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
txtFormat.inputView=inputFormat;
txtType.inputView=inputType;
```

---

My problem comes now:

I want to fill the pickers with different data and I don't know how to do it.
I know how to set the datasource for one picker but not for two.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the delegate methods

---

### UIPickerViewDelegate

```
– numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
– pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:
```

---

You can figure out which `UIPickerView` is asking for it's content by testing the `pickerView` variable. Just connect an outlet to both `UIPickerView`s. So you can select the same object as the data source of the two picker views.

---

### For example

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    if (pickerView == self.firstPickerView) {
        return 10;
    } else if (pickerView == self.secondPickerView) {
        return 15;
    }
}
```

Comment: @oPi You don't have to. It's always best to let the view controller handle it's own content.

Comment: @oPi If be glad if you could accept my answer if it helped you. You can do this by clicking the check icon on the left ;)